# Dynamic formula in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic

I have received an Excel sheet which has two columns, say ColA and ColB. When I enter data in ColA, a formula itself comes in ColB. However, when there is no data in a cell of ColA, corresponding cell in ColB looks empty and there is not even a formula in that cell. The formula comes into the cell of ColB automatically when I put data in corresponding cell of ColA.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted in https://superuser.com/ instead of Stack Overflow ?

Comment: Excel VBA `Sheet_Change` event.

Comment: @mr.mams, why ?

Comment: Well, it seems to be more a question about Excel usage, rather than a programming question. If you search for Excel in superuser.com, you'll find out plenty of questions of that kind.